# Can Polygraphs be effectively 'beaten'?

Tags: physical

[This](https://antipolygraph.org/faq.shtml#q5) article suggests that polygraphs are rather rudimentary and thus very susceptible to being 'beaten'. In pop culture we see all the time movies where polygraphs are beaten -but with great difficulty. Can this truly be done and if so, how difficult is it -does it take great skills and discipline to learn 'tricks' or is the polygraph system itself flawed?

Comment: This isn't an Info Security question ...

Comment: @schroeder, I onced commented the exact same thing, but as I understanding it, we do not generally discourage non-IT related security questions. For example, the site itself is filled with them.

Comment: I grant that we often allow non-IT related questions, I've even asked a few myself. But this is not an Info Security question, IT or not.

Comment: Agreed - While it may be interesting, this is not an information security question.

Answer (score 1):

The reality is they don't work effectively. They test stress and emotional response to stress, which can be an indicator. So you are correct, they can be 'beaten' if the person is stressed by other reasons (such as 'I am being questioned on a lie detector' can be scary enough...) or if someone is a sociopath and has no real response emotionally anyway.

LegalMatch.com has a bit of info on the subject:

"In past times they were often used by police and government agents to interrogate suspected criminals, but as they have been proven to be extremely unreliable indicators of lying..."

http://www.legalmatch.com/law-library/article/admissability-of-polygraph-tests-in-court.html